# Cannot install material design lite for dart

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I cannot seem to install MDL for Dart. My files are very simple.

pubspec.yaml:

```
name: mdl_test
dependencies:
  mdl: "^1.0.0"
  browser: '^0.10.0'
  di: "^3.3.4"
transformers:
  - di
```

main.dart:

```
import 'package:mdl/mdl.dart' as mdl;
main() async {
  mdl.registerMdl();
  await mdl.componentFactory().run();
}
```

I am getting multiple errors.  Example: `Target of URI does not exist: package:logging/logging.dart` - I checked, and logging is downloaded properly.
There are many "Target of URI does not exist" errors as well.  It seems that packages in main.dart are imported fine, but packages installed with pub, that import other packages, are not working.  Does anyone know why this is, or what the fix is?  Thanks.

Comment: Did you run `pub get` or `pub upgrade`?

Comment: Yes, I tried both.  Sorry, I should have given more information.  I am using the Atom editor with the dartlang plugin.  The analysis catches these errors, and the code does not run because of them.  I also tried to add logging to the dependencies on pubspec.yaml, even though the package is already downloaded without that, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: You could also try `pub cache repair`. I didn't try Atom myself yet. Did you run `pub upgrade` from Atom or from command line?

Comment: I've tried the pub get, pub upgrade from Atom as well as the command line.  No luck.  pub cache repair doesn't seem to do it either.  I tried this multiple times, deleted the files, and recreated them, but still the same errors occur.

Comment: Was a `packages` directory created in your project directory?

Comment: It was, and it included the packages to which the errors are referring.  I tried to run the programs, hoping these are false positive errors, but it does not work.  I even tried to import using the symlinks, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Weird, have you tried run `pub serve` from command line and then open the page from Dartium like `http://localhost:8080/index.html`?

Comment: The problem seems to be in the packages.  I cannot even get past that without errors.  The web page does render, but not with the mdl activated.  Thank you, Gunter.  But Stackoverflow is getting upset with me because of the extended discussion.  I'll send this over to G+ and see if anyone else has this experience in the Dart community.  I really appreciate the help.

Comment: You don't need to worry about the message to move to chat. I usually clean up obsolete comments when the cause was revealed. But you can of course move to G+ or maybe the Dart Slack channel.